# WinSock (VB6) vs Socket em C#

Tags: c#, .net, socket, visual-basic-6

Tenho um código em VB6 que utiliza a MSWINSCK.OCX para enviar comandos a um equipamento, o código está abaixo. Porém tenho que mudar para C# e estou tentado usar a classe Sockets, o problema que estou enfrentando é que o programa em C#, usando Sockets, não está recebendo a resposta do equipamento. Em VB6, usando MSWINSCK.OCX, funciona normal eu consigo enviar os comandos e receber a resposta.

Código VB6

```
Private Sub CmdClear_Click()
   TxtRcv.Text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub CmdSend_Click()
   WinSock.RemoteHost = "255.255.255.255" 'ip do equipamento'
   WinSock.SendData TxtSend.Text
End Sub

Private Sub WinSock_DataArrival(ByVal bytesTotal As Long)
   WinSock.GetData s$
   TxtRcv.Text = TxtRcv.Text + s$ + Chr$(13) + Chr$(10)
End Sub
```

Código C# usando Sockets

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.25.200");

        var hostep = new IPEndPoint(host, 3000);

        var sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified);

        try
        {
            sock.Connect(hostep);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem connecting to host");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            sock.Close();
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            sock.SendTo(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("V"), hostep);
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem sending data");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            sock.Close();
            return;
        }

        var receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(3000);

        try
        {
            var receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref hostep);

            var returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Console.WriteLine("Mensagem recebida " + returnData);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        sock.Close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual equipamento ?

Comment: é um Tibbo. http://www.tibbo.com

Comment: Ja viu o artigo de Sockets? https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Colocou o Socket em modo de escuta (`Socket.Listen()`)? Se estiver usando um protocolo TCP recomendo habilitar e executar esse método nas primeiras declarações do soquete. se estiver usando UDP, verifique se as proteções do IP estão declaradas para Edge (`Erestricted`) ou não-restritas (`Unrestricted`), para alterar a proteção use o método `SetIPProtection`.

Answer (score 0):

Você abriu um socket chamado "sock", fez uma conexão, e enviou uma string, no caso a letra "V". Mas do nada, você abre um "UdpClient" e ignora totalmente o socket aberto chamado "sock"... Pelo que estou entendendo você quer mandar uma string e receber outra string. Talvez seja melhor deixar o socket de lado e usar uma classe melhor para isso, o TcpClient ela é melhor pois você pode trabalhar com Stream o que já torna mais fácil para não ficar trabalhando direto com array de bytes. olha um exemplo:

```
        var host = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.25.200");
        var hostep = new IPEndPoint(host, 3000);

        var tcpClient = new TcpClient(hostep);

        using (var wr = new StreamWriter(tcpClient.GetStream()))
        using (var rd = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream()))
        {
            wr.WriteLine("V");
            wr.Flush();
            var retorno = rd.ReadLine();
        }
```